# printing directories code on UNIX makes error

Tags: c, unix, posix, command-line-arguments, ls

I've been studying UNIX and there's a example code on the book,

but this code seems not working. When I compile the code, returns segmentation error.

```
#include<dirent.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>

int my_double_ls(const char *name)
{
   struct dirent *d;
   DIR *dp;

   if ((dp=opendir(name)) == NULL)
    return (-1);

   while (d=readdir(dp)) {
    if (d->d_ino != 0)
        printf("%s\n", d->d_name);
   }

   rewinddir(dp);

  while (d = readdir(dp)) {
    if (d->d_ino != 0)
        printf("%s\n", d->d_name);
  }

  closedir(dp);
  return(0);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){

  my_double_ls(argv[1]);

  return(0);
}
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Are you sure you told us everything? How do you compile? What is your platform? How do you run the program? Did you try to debug this? Did you run the program from an IDE without specifying and command line?

Comment: BTW: unrelated, but don't write `return(0)`, just write `return 0`. `return(0)` is not actually wrong, but is just looks like a function call (which it isn't) and it's unusual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably invoked the program without command line arguments:

Try this:

```
...
int main(int argc, char **argv){
  if (argc < 2)
  {
     printf("You need to specify the directory.\n");
     exit(1);
  }

  my_double_ls(argv[1]);
  return 0;
}
```

The `my_double_ls` function looks more or less correct to me.

Comment: my bad. I forgot to write directory command line arguments. Thanks anyway :)